# PHP: File upload move_uploaded_file() method not working for IIS7

Tags: php

When I was using XAMPP server and MySQL database that time it was working, but I have to use MSSQL database IIS7 server where its not working. See This is the html form:

```
<form action="bookentry.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
   <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Book Image</td>
        <td>
        <label>
            <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
        </label>
        </td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
      <label>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Book Now" />
     </label>
     </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
```

And this the php code

```
<?php
    $bid="MyImageName";
    $newname = "$bid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory.php"); 
    exit();
?>
```

I don't understand the problem and where it occurs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you've `write permission` to the folder in which you're trying to move that file.(`inventory_images`).

EDIT

as per your comment to check permissions in `windows` OS:

`right click` that folder go to `properties` and then go to `security tab`

From that you can also give the permission by simply checking the `checkbox` and then clicking on `apply` button.

Here is screen shot to help:

[image]

Comment: How to gain write permission?

Comment: @mhtamun, have a look at EDIT

Comment: @mhtamun, after changing permission? or what?

Comment: after changing permission

Comment: @mhtamun Then it'll be nice if you post your `html` and full `php` code in order to make it more understandable.

Comment: Now Please Check @Vedant Terkar

Comment: @mhtamun, You havent provided php code yet. Just two questions: 1. Is `$bid` is a variable in php? does it have some value? 2. have you wrapped your php code inside `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: If you now kindly please check again?

Comment: @mhtamun, Your code looks fine,and works for me after changing permission. sorry cant help. How ever can suggest you to use m code with error reporting for file uploading. To get exact error.